# Pairing a bluetooth speaker and playing music via the cli

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to use a bluetooth speaker as an input and output device.  It works fine with my phone, so the speaker and bluetooth is functional.  End goal is to use it like a google assistant, since it has a speaker and a microphone on it (testing to see if I can use the microphone).

I use

```
$: bluetoothctl
$: power on
$: agent on
$: default-agent
$: scan on
#waiting to get mac address
$: pair (macaddress)
Attempting to pair with 1D:34:BE:73:C3:CD
[CHG] Device 1D:34:BE:73:C3:CD Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 1D:34:BE:73:C3:CD UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 1D:34:BE:73:C3:CD UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 1D:34:BE:73:C3:CD UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 1D:34:BE:73:C3:CD UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 1D:34:BE:73:C3:CD ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 1D:34:BE:73:C3:CD Paired: yes
Pairing successful
#about 5 seconds  later
[CHG] Device 1D:34:BE:73:C3:CD ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 1D:34:BE:73:C3:CD Connected: no
```

Any attempts to connect to it after this fail.  Any attempt to play music over it fails.  This is a headless system so I can't really use the GUI, as it is disabled, though I can use anything that can be forwarded via x server.

I am a bit perplexed by this...

Comment: Welcome to the "Perplexed Club"  :)  I've got the same issue, and [recently posted a similar question here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95532/bluetooth-blues). My question has links to a couple of suggestions I tried that didn't work for me, but others have reported they did work for them. Beyond that, all I can offer is a "Good Luck". If you do find an answer, please post it here; we're not the only ones struggling with this.

Comment: @Seamus After spending all day I got it to work.. problem is I have no idea what it was that finally fixed the issue. :(

Comment: Not to worry... I think that happens frequently! And then, to add to the confusion, they publish a "tutorial" on their blog because they believe they know what they did to make it work :)  I feel it's a murky area sorely in need of some organization and better (clearer, not more) documentation. I'm glad to hear you got it working... and also glad you won't be publishing a blog on your solution  :)

Answer (score 1):

Somethings that seemed to have made it work.  I am using pulseaudio.  From what I read you shouldn't do this with Raspian stretch, which should instead use Bluez-alsa.  however, this isn't in the package repositories for me and installation didn't fix anything so I am saying what kind of got it working.

1. make sure you have bluetooth modules for pulseaudio installed. 
   `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`
2. Reboot bluetooth `sudo systemctl stop bluetooth && sudo systemctl start bluetooth`
3. Restart pulseaudio `pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -D`
4. unload and load pulseaudio module `pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-policy && pactl load-module module-bluetooth-policy`
5. Use `bluetoothctl` to pair your device

Your device might pair now.  I find I have to do unload and reload the bluetooth-policy module for pulse audio every time I reconnect (Step 4).  Super annoying.

Comment: I've just read [Youness' "tutorial"](https://youness.net/raspberry-pi/how-to-connect-bluetooth-headset-or-speaker-to-raspberry-pi-3) on these Bluetooth issues. If his research & conclusions are accurate, the RPi 3B+ Bluetooth hardware is pretty much useless as far as streaming sound (unless you're a masochist, and like low quality playback :)

Comment: @seamus  I installed the latest version of Raspian and it works great via the user interface with blue-alsa.  Streams like a pro.  Was also very easy to set up.  I just did sup apt-get install blue-alsa, and then connected via the desktop and started streaming  to the speaker.  However, just can't get sound from the microphone back.

Comment: Terrific! Hope to get back and get mine working soon :)

Answer (score 0):

I found these guides particularly useful, and helped me solve playing audio over bluetooth speaker issue.

[CONNECT BLUETOOTH HEADPHONES WITH YOUR RASPBERRY PI](https://peppe8o.com/fixed-connect-bluetooth-headphones-with-your-raspberry-pi/)

If `aplay ... PROFILE=sco` doesn't work for you, try changing it to `a2dp` and use *bluetoothd with a2dp plugin*. ([Guide here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90267/how-to-stream-sound-to-a-bluetooth-device-from-a-raspberry-pi-zero))

FYI. `aplay` doesn't support *mp3* files, try `mpg123` or `omxplayer` instead.