# Raspbian and Bluetooth Headset not working

Tags: bluetooth

I know, there are already several questions about this, but none of them helped me. I have a rasbian installation and try to connect to my bluetooth headset.

When I run `sudo bluetoothctl` I can find the headset, I can `pair` it and I can `trust` it, but trying to connect I get an error:

```
$connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:21
Attempting to connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:21
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

In the syslog (`sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i protocol`) I see:

```
....
Jan 26 22:24:29 raspberrypi bluetoothd[363]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:21: Protocol not available
Jan 26 22:24:51 raspberrypi pulseaudio[1007]: Failed to load module "module-native-protocol-unix" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
Jan 26 22:24:53 raspberrypi bluetoothd[363]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:21: Protocol not available
Jan 26 22:24:55 raspberrypi bluetoothd[363]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:21: Protocol not available
Jan 26 22:24:56 raspberrypi bluetoothd[363]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:21: Protocol not available
Jan 26 22:26:07 raspberrypi bluetoothd[363]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:21: Protocol not available
Jan 26 22:26:20 raspberrypi bluetoothd[363]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:21: Protocol not available
Jan 26 22:26:21 raspberrypi bluetoothd[363]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:21: Protocol not available
Jan 26 22:26:21 raspberrypi bluetoothd[363]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:21: Protocol not available
Jan 26 22:26:23 raspberrypi bluetoothd[363]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:21: Protocol not available
Jan 26 22:32:30 raspberrypi bluetoothd[363]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:21: Protocol not available
Jan 26 22:35:00 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1497]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:21: Protocol not available
Jan 26 22:39:25 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1497]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:21: Protocol not available
```

I already tried a couple of suggested solutions, like reinstalling `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` (https://askubuntu.com/a/1228816) or module loading (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/67665 which is based on this: https://askubuntu.com/a/689297).

I still can't load the `module-bluetooth-discover`:

```
$sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't just using the Bluetooth widget on the Menu bar?

Comment: Yes. I have no gui and I even don't have a screen. I just connecting to my device by ssh.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the **Lite** RPi OS (or maybe even the "medium" one), you should know that there are substantial differences in the level of Bluetooth support.

Depending upon which of the [**three distro versions**](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/) you've installed, setting up your Bluetooth headset can be quite simple (as in Milliways comment), or it can be a [complete *nutroll*](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/nut-roll) - as [documented in this "answer".](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/116843/83790)

Hope that helps... in other words, this can be straightforward, or it can be difficult, depending on which distro you've installed.

**EDIT, 20210127:** I've learned of [another "How-To Guide"](https://peppe8o.com/fixed-connect-bluetooth-headphones-with-your-raspberry-pi/) for using Bluetooth on the ***Lite*** version of RPi OS. I've not tried it myself, but like mine, it also looks to be in the *nutroll class* of solutions; any feedback is welcomed.

Comment: I am using Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) without a gui (I use it as an audio box für my child) and since I invested already about 5 hours with it, it looks like we are at a nutroll level ;)

Comment: You have my sympathy. The "answer" I referenced above was done to get a Bluetooth speaker working. I *imagine* that getting headphones to work is mostly the same. If so, this will likely be of some help. It's been a while since I worked through that, but feel free to ask questions if you get stuck. And - feel free to add your edits to the nutroll.

Comment: @bernhardh: One other thing that might help: At the bottom of the Comment section to my QUESTION there are links to a chatroom session between myself & ukBaz (who was hugely helpful). I don't know that they'll be useful, but feel free to peruse those also.